# how can i add custom page number for laravel mpdf using setFooter

Tags: laravel, mpdf

i have 4 page in my pdf and i want to show page number in footer for page number 1 and 2 like page number 1 and page number 2, but for my 4th page i want to add page number 1 in footer or** i want restart page number from 4th page**. how can i do this , below is the code snippet

```
**$document = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([ 
 'mode' => 'utf-8',  
 'format' => 'A4'
]);

$document->defaultheaderline = 0;
    $document->defaultfooterline = 0;
    $document->setFooter('<div style="text-align: center">Page No. {PAGENO}</div>');
    $document->WriteHTML($content); **
```

i tried with custom  page 1 by footer tag but its now working, i want to do this work from mpdf library.